# Keep alive and Max_client issue in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, web-server, ubuntu-11.04, keepalive

I have installed Apache/2.2.17 on ubuntu 11.4(64bit) ,with 48 GB of RAM, and set

```
KeepAlive ON
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
keepalivetimeout to 6 (since  lot of dynamic images) 
StartServers          100
MinSpareServers       100
MaxSpareServers       150
ServerLimit           300
MaxClients            300
MaxRequestsPerChild   3000
```

But the problem is Apache is usually reaching its max-clients even with 10-20 users,and after restart its reaching near to 185 with in first 10-15 minutes and not coming down.Can anyone help in finding the reason for it..

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing fully what is going on with your system when this happens (see below), here are a couple of suggestions:

1. First, lower your start servers to something like 10, and same for MinSpare and MaxSpare. The high numbers you have might be eating up your memory when the web server starts up.
2. Second, try setting your `MaxKeepAliveRequests` to a high value: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#maxkeepaliverequests . The default is `100`, so try increasing in increments of 100 (or any number you find suitable), and see if get to a sweet spot. You can also try `0`, for  "unlimited amount."

Also, update your question with what the system is doing when this happens. It is out of memory and swapping (`free -m`)? Is the CPU pegged? What do you see out of `top`? What else are you running on this box?